# Excel COMException Hresult: 0x800a03ec when I try to Activate a workbook through C# code using Interop

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, excel-interop

I am running multiple Excel workbooks in a WPF application, embedded in a WebBrowser. I am trying to implement a way to switch between the workbooks. The way to do this is I figured, by Activating the required workbook if it is already in the list of workbooks of the running Excel application.

Code:

```
internal void ActivateWorkBook(string wbName)
 {
    var xlApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") as Excel.Application;
    ((Excel._Workbook)xlApp.Workbooks[wbName]).Activate();
 }
```

I get the exception at the `Activate()` function.
Does anybody have a solution for this problem?

I know that I can switch between the workbooks by using `WebBrowsers.Navigate(filePath)`. But I would like to do it with the above technique.